# Which test should I use for the effect of a binary treatment on many continuous outcomes measured at 3 time points, controlling for baseline values?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I have a binary treatment, and 6 continuous outcomes (at least, they can take from 21 to 49 distinct values), all measured  at baseline and at 3 time points after the treatment. I was thinking about the following global tests on whether or not (given baseline values):

1) for each post-treatment time point, the treatment has an effect on the joint distribution of outcomes;

2) for each outcome, the treatment has an effect on the joint distribution of its values in $t_1$, $t_2$ and $t_3$.

Thus, both are tests about conditional independence between treatment and outcomes, given baseline values, but in one case I’m doing 3 tests (one for each given time point) about 6 outcomes; in the other one 6 tests (one for each outcome) about 3 time points: 9 tests in total.
I was thinking about using **seemingly unrelated regression** for 1 (using 2 covariates for each regression: treatment status and the baseline value of the score) and **mixed ANCOVA** for 2 (with 2 groups, 3 time-periods and again controlling for the value at baseline), testing (in both cases) for the joint significance of the parameters related to treatment status.
My question is: **how can I make a global test of no effect of treatment on any outcome at any time?** This would be a joint test of no effect for 18 parameters (6 outcomes x 3 time points).

Comment: sorry to be curt, but this might help: http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/231-2011.pdf

Comment: Thank you. Yes: it seems it is precisely what I was looking for. Do you (or does anyone) know how to perform it in Stata?